# Jade template failed to render javascript correctly

Tags: node.js, templates, express, pug

I have a question about including scripts from blocks

From express-generator,

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        block content
        include sidebar
    script(src='/javascripts/jquery.js')
    block bottomscripts
```

**sidebar.jade**

```
block bottomscripts
    script(src='/javascripts/sidebar.js')
```

**output**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Express</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Express</h1>
        <p>Welcome to Express</p>
        <script src="/javascripts/sidebar.js">
        </script><script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
      </body>
</html>
```

how can i move sidebar.js below jquery.js ? i need this done inside sidebar.jade

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including jquery.js in your block? Seems like they are both "bottomscripts".

```
block bottomscripts
    script(src='/javascripts/jquery.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/sidebar.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

So can move your include statement and change the indentation of your jquery sctipt statement to

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        block content        
        script(src='/javascripts/jquery.js')
        include sidebar
    block bottomscripts
```

to get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/sidebar.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```